# PostgreSQL procedure to insert a sequence of random numbers in a column

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, random, sql-insert

I need to insert `k` random numbers (in the range `1:n`) concatenated by `|` into a column of a table `'X'`, where `n` is the number of rows in table `'Y'`, in a PostgreSQL procedure.

To find the number of rows in the table `'Y'`

`select count(*) into n from Y`

This will generate `k` random numbers in the range `1:n`

`SELECT num FROM GENERATE_SERIES (1, n) AS s(num) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT k;`

How do I concatenate the `k` integers with `|` and insert them into `'X'`?

Comment: Try `string_agg`

Comment: You claim that "n" is the number of _columns_ in table `y` - but `select count(*) into n from Y` returns the number of **rows** in that table. Two very different things. Also: storing delimited values in a column is almost always a really bad idea. A properly normalized model is much easier to maintain and to work with

Comment: @Bergi with `string_agg` I need to pass the output of the query as the first argument, would I have to use a temporary table to hold the results of the query for generating the `k` random numbers or is there any other optimal way?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for pointing that out, my bad, I corrected it to the number of rows. My use case is that I need to assign a random set of rows from multiple tables to a user for a task and need to maintain the assignments in a table.

Comment: Still: you shouldn't store delimited values in  a single column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name true, would be useful if you can suggest an alternative to doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `insert ... select` and string aggregation function `string_agg()`:

```
insert into y (x)
select string_agg(num::text, '|')
from (select num from generate_series (1, n) as s(num) order by random() limit k) s
```

Note that you need `n` to be equal to or greater than `k` for this technique to make sense.